# Why does x axis not increment 'monthly' chart.js. Also, XAxis not taking title

Tags: chart.js

https://water.sas.usace.army.mil/chart.htm
https://water.sas.usace.army.mil/chart.png
`See the Code Above, (View Source)`
`The code builds a time-series chart.`
`The scales section has unit set to month, however chart does not display with monthly increment on x axis.`
`Also Y axis will not display title.`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that `config` is not properly formatted, `options.plugins` is not closed by a `}`, hence the entire `scales` section is not considered by Chart.js.

Further, you should also define a [`time.parser`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#parser) to let the date adapter know how to parse the provided date strings.

> Be careful to choose the correct [date-fns formats](https://date-fns.org/docs/format) for `time.parser` as well as for `time.displayFormats`.

Therefore, if you define `config` as follows, it should work.

```
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "HARTWELL PROJECT",
        font: {
          size: 20
        }
      },
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          parser: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
          unit: 'month',
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMM yyyy'
          }
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Date'
        }
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          position: 'left',
          display: true,
          text: 'Elevation (FT-MSL)'
        }
      }
    },
    chartAreaBorder: {
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 10,
      //borderDash: [5, 5],
      borderDashOffset: 5
    },
    imgPlugin: {}
  },
  plugins: [chartAreaBorder, imgPlugin, GradientBgPlugin]
};
```